# Different behaviour of links in site navigation

Tags: navigation

I'm working on a website for an IT firm. It is mostly a single page website with only two exceptions (Careers, Data Privacy).

Is it considered bad practice to have a navigation bar where some of the entries jump to parts on the same page (like About Us, Products, ...) while the two exceptions jump to a different page?

And if so, what would be a clean approach to separate the two?

Answer (score 1):

Keep it consistent, either all the links link to separate pages, or they all link to sections within the page.

I would recommend you building the separate pages because that way your client can have links to share or post anywhere they want. Rather than driving people to the homepage and either having item click the link section, or landing halfway down the page (which is kind of awkward as their first intro the the website).

Answer (score 0):

You can add 1 position shortcut, where you can add these positions.

If its possible you can add these option in layout as buttons.

Comment: Hello Mateusz, can you explain *why* this should be the way to go? Right now, this is not an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Keep all of them on the single page.

Comment: Why do you think this is the best solution?